# Axios not sending headers to rails controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, ruby, axios

I am on Rails 5.1.7 with a react frontend with react-rails gem

My problem looks like what is explained [here](https://medium.com/@zayneabraham/ruby-on-rails-csrf-protection-with-react-js-65dd84b8edad) just that my react components are server rendered so I can not access data from the client from the component.

So I have created the following file:

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default function() {
  const csrfToken = document.querySelector("meta[name=csrf-token]").content;
  axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = csrfTokens;
}
```

and I import in in application.js as:

```
import setupCSRFToken from '../setupCSRFToken'
```

and then calling the exported function.

The problem is that checking the headers the controller does not receive anything:

```
(byebug) request.headers['X-CSRF-Token'] 
nil
```

so the problem must be related with how axios is configurated. I did install it with:

```
yarn add axios
```

in the developer console I get:

```
xhr.js:179 POST http://localhost:3000/es/roomlist_reorder 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:179
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js:20
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:40
Promise.then (async)
request @ Axios.js:64
Axios.<computed> @ Axios.js:88
wrap @ bind.js:11
RoomList._this.getOrder @ roomlist.jsx:33
RoomList._this.filterRooms @ roomlist.jsx:47
RoomList._this.handleOrderBy @ roomlist.jsx:51
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:191
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:240
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:293
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:308
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:393
executeDispatchesInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:418
executeDispatchesAndRelease @ react-dom.development.js:3303
executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js:3312
forEachAccumulated @ react-dom.development.js:3284
runEventsInBatch @ react-dom.development.js:3329
runExtractedPluginEventsInBatch @ react-dom.development.js:3539
handleTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js:3583
batchedEventUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:21731
batchedEventUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:800
dispatchEventForLegacyPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:3593
attemptToDispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:4313
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:4234
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:661
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11079
discreteUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:21748
discreteUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:813
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:4213
roomlist.jsx:40 Error: Request failed with status code 422
    at createError (createError.js:17)
    at settle (settle.js:19)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:69)
```

headers:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/es/roomlist_reorder
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 422 Unprocessable Entity
Remote Address: [::1]:3000
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Request-Id: 2de02308-5eff-4e68-8a07-f39dfdf
X-Runtime: 0.145234
X-Web-Console-Mount-Point: /__web_console
X-Web-Console-Session-Id: 57baf1f81457b91c49fa8
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 24
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8

....
```

request headers:

```
:authority: m.stripe.com
:method: POST
:path: /6
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
content-length: 656
content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
cookie: private_machine_identifier=tKQmcfYNS9%BJ86cfKvXcvBodWTYUWwUkE%3D; m=306ba65-c03-4b-8257-2b6d9bde3d44; 
session=sess_I4LBSZAr2S0DM8i
origin: https://m.stripe.network
referer: https://m.stripe.network/
sec-ch-ua: "\\Not;A\"Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="85", "Chromium";v="85"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
```

Comment: Can you show the request info from the developer console on your browser? That way we can see whether the header is in fact being sent to the backend

Comment: I have updated the question with that at the end

Comment: That's the console log. It would be nice to see the data from the tab "Network", which shows requests and responses. Clicking in that request on particular will show all the information regarding it, including headers sent.

Comment: I have updated with the request headers

Comment: Can you add console debugging to `export default function() {` to see if it's a) being called and b) able to get the CSRF token from the DOM at the time its invoked? Can you also add some other arbitrary header to axios from where ever you are calling that exported function to see if you're having issues adding anything to axios headers?